# Date Filter Between Date Odd Behaviour

Tags: views, datetime

Hello i am having problems showing nodes created between '8 days ago and 38 days ago' in my Views filters.

filter Node: Post date: is between
 An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"
Min: -8 days
Max: +38 days

Im not getting the required behaviour. if i trim it down to

Min: -3 days
Max +5 days

it seems to be filtering. With my original -8 and + 38 though its showing all the nodes. Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar type of issue and managed to fix it by changing back to "Single Filter" and adjusting the filter value type to what I wanted to use in "Grouped filters" type. I then went back to "Grouped Filter" and my date filters suddenly started working.

Alternatively, you can just delete the filter and add it again, and try set it correctly from the start.

Hope that helps.

p.s. using Views 7.x-3.6